# The name does not exist in the current context infopath custom code

Tags: xpath, sharepoint, infopath

I'm using the below code to swap between drop down items on an infopath form, I thought the initial error might be due to misnamed namespace but that looks fine. I was then told it was due to the partial class, that's been added but the error remains:

```
namespace Form1
{
    public partial class FormCode
    {

        public void InternalStartup()
        {



            XPathNavigator xnDocument = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();



            XPathNavigator xnDefaultView = xnDocument.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:duration", this.NamespaceManager);



            if ((xnDefaultView != null) && (xnDefaultView.Value != ""))

            {

                switch (xnDefaultView.Value)

                {

                    case "false":

                        e.SetDefaultView("Partial");

                        break;



                    case "true":

                        e.SetDefaultView("Full");

                        break;

}}}}}
```

The name 'e' does not exist in the current context, I assume this has something to do with the placing of my if statement, but I'm not making any headway.

Comment: What is `e` supposed to be? Where is it declared?

Comment: That's not C++. Tag removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = this.NamespaceManager;
XPathNavigator FormNavigator = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
string value = FormNavigator.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:txtField", NamespaceManager).Value;
if (value != null && value != "") 
{
   FormNavigator.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:ddField", ns).SetValue("full");
}
else
{
   FormNavigator.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:ddField", ns).SetValue("empty");
}
```